# How can we block Ruby on Rails on a Memcached read so it doesn't eat CPU?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asynchronous, memcached, parallel-processing

We have a daemon which scans a table for dirty bits and then schedules dirty rows to a delayed_job in batches.  In order to avoid a constant `select from data where dirty = 1`, we set up a memcached barrier, which wraps the table scan, like

```
   loop do # daemon
     until Rails.cache.fetch("have_dirty_rows") do end
     page = 1
     loop do # paginate dirty rows
       dirty_batch = paginate(#:select     => "*",
                           :order      => "id",
                           :per_page   => DIRTY_GET_BATCH_SIZE,
                           :conditions => {:dirty => 1},
                           :page       => page)
       if dirty_batch.empty?
         Rails.cache.write("have_dirty_rows",false)
         break
       end
       ...
       page = page.next
     end
   end
```

Unless I add some `sleep 0.0001` or such, the loop eats 100% CPU still.  Is there an efficient mechanism in Ruby/Rails which will block on something like the memcached value, or which we can feed from a memcached value, so it's not polling all the time?

Comment: Doubt it. Polling is cumbersome, but works well for interfacing many different types of processes. The only other way would be a cronjob that I can think of.

Comment: Examine the issue one step before this solution that will kill a server, meaning, where does the dirty rows comes from?
Can't you really do something in code the moment you know you are setting dirty bits?

Comment: In fact, I'm wondering how the wait is implemented in general, such as for an AMQP client.  There are many cases where you don't have control of the source of the values you're watching to change...

Answer (score 1):

Active polling is BAD !
Where are the dirty bits comin from?
It woul be better if this process uses a message queue mechanism (eg RabbitMQ ) to notify other processes. That something has changed in the database.

Comment: The question about an ability to block a Ruby process.  RabbitMQ is indeed a consideration, but blocking is interesting in itself...

Comment: mmh, maybe this will help you: http://makandra.com/notes/1026-simple-database-mutex